# How to make a standalone application appear on the Mint menu?

Tags: linux-mint

How can I make the executable file of a standalone application appear on the mint menu so that I can execute it from there? What I currently do is to add the application path to the `PATH` variable and execute it from command line like this: `AppName &`. I don't know how I can add the application to the mint menu though. Any advice would be appreciated. I am on `Linux Mint 15 (Mate)`.

Comment: tl;dr: look in `/usr/share/applications`. copypasta. modify to have values for your application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to create the mint menu entry yourself, just run the following command:

```
sudo mate-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications --create-new
```

A window will appear, just give it a name, then type the command to use a web-browser to open the website URL. Also change the shortcut icon.
Now I got a launcher for testapp at `/usr/share/applications/testapp.desktop`.

Source [here](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/06/mint-menu-always-show-favorite-applications.html)